# Can i get my Event Receiver source code from a WSP file

Tags: 2013, development, visual-studio, solution-package, farm-solution

I was working on a sharepoint 2013 farm solution to implement an event receiver inside visual studio 2012 professional. now when i try to build/run the project i got an error that there is not space on the disk. so i closed Visual Studio, free some space on the server, re-open the project. but i found that my code inside the ER `.cs` file have been removed (almost half the code has been removed!!).

but i have the `.wsp` file for my project, so i am not sure if i can rely on this `.wsp` to get mt ER `.c`s source code?. now i try to change the file extendion from `.wsp` to .`cab`, where i got those files:-

[image]

but unfortunatly none of them contain the ER `.cs` code. so can anyone adivce on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use free trial of [.Net Reflector tool](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to view the source code of `dll` files.

Decompiled Source code would not be the exact same as that was in your `.cs` files but you will get an overall idea of your source code.

Comment: @Yatati I used a tool named dotPeek where i was able to decompile my .dll and get the event receiver source code, but i  have noted that on the decomplied source code all the comments have been removed + all the variables got new names such as `str1` `str2` instead of the friendly names i use to have.... also i use to have some `public override` methods which were changed to `public virtual`.. so not sure if i should trust this decomplied source code..

Comment: Yep decompilation is never going to give you back your source, rather it’s re-created from what the compiler already turned your source into. Better than nothing in this case. As for trusting it, you could re-compile from the de-compiled source and run your tests against it to satisfy yourself.